# Conventional For Loop vs Enhanced For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

This code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i : arr) System.out.println(arr[i]);



    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
2
3
4
1
2
```

With this Input:

```
5 1
1 2 3 4 1
```

On the other hand 
This Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) System.out.println(arr[i]);



    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
1
```

In the first code snippet the foreach loop should print the elements of the array but I don't understand what are those numbers and how those numbers are the elements of that array.

Comment: What do you think is `i` here: `for(int i : arr)`? What values does it hold?

Comment: @Tom I think it work as an iterator holding the elements of array one at a time.

Comment: Correct, then why do you write `System.out.println(arr[i])`?

Comment: @Tom I get it thanks man. I should print i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because herein following line,

```
for(int i : arr) System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

you are printing `arr[i]`  rather than `i` itself
here `arr[i]` tries to access element at 1,2,3,4 and 1 which is as below according to your input

```
arr[0]-->1
arr[1]-->2
arr[2]-->3
arr[3]-->4
arr[4]-->1
```

**However Enhanced for loop gives value not the index on each iteration**

replace it with the following line and you will see the same output

```
for(int i : arr) System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced `for` loop gives you the *values*, but you're using them as *indices*.  To make the enhanced `for` loop equivalent to the traditional `for` loop, just use the value instead of accessing the array.

```
for(int value : arr) System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the conventional loop first:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

In this case, `i` is the index into the array `arr`.  So when you write:

```
`arr[i]`, you're getting the element at position `i`.
```

Now the enhanced for loop:

```
for(int i : arr) System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

In this case, `i` is *not* an index, but is instead **the value stored in the array**.  So when you write `arr[i]`, what you're doing is taking a value out of the array (`i`), treating as if it were an index, and getting the value out of the array at that new index.

If you want your enhanced loop to function the way you expect, do this:

```
for(int i : arr) System.out.println(i);
```

Though using `i` as a variable name there is poor practice, since it's usually expected that `i` is an index, so use some name other than `i` there if you want to make the code clearer.